# The \caption command in an algorithm block gives this error: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I'm trying to write a caption to my algorithm in LaTeX, but something seems to not work. When I compile my code, I get some weird symbols in my caption, and a *Missing number, treated as zero* error. (see the picture at the end)
However, when I delete the *caption* command, the code compiles just fine!
I'd be thankful, if you could help.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]

\SetKwInput{Var}{Variables}
\SetKwInput{Alg}{Algorithm}
\SetKwData{D}{d}\SetKwData{Eps}{eps}\SetKwData{Min}{minPts}
\SetKwData{M}{m}\SetKwData{N}{n}\SetKwData{Dist}{dist}
\SetKwData{Indices}{indices}\SetKwData{Classn}{class\_no}
\SetKwData{Nei}{neighbors}\SetKwData{Neic}{neighbor\_count}
\SetKwData{Core}{core\_neig}\SetKwData{Class}{class}
\SetKwData{Point}{point}

\SetKwFunction{Distance}{distance}
\SetKwFunction{Find}{find}
\SetKwFunction{Count}{count}
\SetKwFunction{Check}{check\_core\_neighbour}

 \KwIn{\\
 \D: the dataset\\
 \Eps: the neighbourhood distance \\
 \Min: the minimum number of points
 }
 \KwOut{\\Discovered outliers and clusters }
 \Var{\\
 \M, \N: row and column values of \D matrix, respectively\\
 \Dist: distance vector\\
 \Indices: indices that distance of points is lower than \Eps\\
 \Classn: indicates the clusters - default 1}
\BlankLine

\Alg{\\
    import the dataset into \D\\
    \For{$i \leftarrow 1$ \KwTo \M}{
        \Dist $\leftarrow \Distance(i, \D)$\\
        \Nei$\leftarrow$\Find(\Dist$\leq$\Eps)\\
        \Neic$\leftarrow$\Count(\Nei)\\
        \Core$\leftarrow$\Check(\Nei)\\
    
        \uIf{(\Neic$\geq$\Min)}{
            \Class($i$)$\leftarrow$\Classn\\
            \While{more points near $i$}{
                \Class(\Point)=\Classn
            }
            \Classn$\leftarrow$\Classn $+1$
        }
        \uElseIf{(\Neic$<$\Min$\&\&$\Core$==$true)}{
            \Class($i$)$\leftarrow 0$\tcc*[r]{border point}
        }
        \uElseIf{(\Neic$<$\Min)}{
            \Class($i$)$\leftarrow -1$\tcc*[r]{outlier point}
        }
    }
    \KwRet{\Class}
}
 \BlankLine
 \caption{DBSCAN \cite{ccelik2011anomaly}}
 \label{alg:db}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image: the output]

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a contrived error. It happens that

```
\SetKwData{M}{m}
```

not only defines `\M`, but also an internal macro called `\@M` which is already preempted by the LaTeX kernel. This redefinition happens with no check for `\@M` already being defined.

In the LaTeX kernel, `\@M` stands for 10000 and is used in several places for the value of a penalty that prohibits line or page breaks.

Use

```
\SetKwData{MM}{m}
```

and `\MM` in the body of the algorithm; or choose an altogether different name.

If you feel bold, you can fix the wrong strategy of `algorithm2e`; also `\SetKw` suffers from the same problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
%%% fix the wrong code in algorithm2e
\renewcommand{\SetKwData}[2]{%
  \algocf@newcommand{algocf@kwdata@#1}[1]{\DataSty{#2(}\ArgSty{##1}\DataSty{)}}%
  \algocf@newcommand{#1}{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\csname algocf@kwdata@#1\endcsname}{\DataSty{#2}\xspace}}%
  }%
\renewcommand{\SetKw}[2]{%
        \algocf@newcommand{algocf@kw@#1}[1]{\KwSty{#2} \ArgSty{##1}}
        \algocf@newcommand{#1}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\csname algocf@kw@#1\endcsname}{\KwSty{#2}\xspace}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetKwInput{Var}{Variables}
\SetKwInput{Alg}{Algorithm}
\SetKwData{D}{d}\SetKwData{Eps}{eps}\SetKwData{Min}{minPts}
\SetKwData{M}{m}\SetKwData{N}{n}\SetKwData{Dist}{dist}
\SetKwData{Indices}{indices}\SetKwData{Classn}{class\_no}
\SetKwData{Nei}{neighbors}\SetKwData{Neic}{neighbor\_count}
\SetKwData{Core}{core\_neig}\SetKwData{Class}{class}
\SetKwData{Point}{point}

\SetKwFunction{Distance}{distance}
\SetKwFunction{Find}{find}
\SetKwFunction{Count}{count}
\SetKwFunction{Check}{check\_core\_neighbour}

 \KwIn{\\
 \D: the dataset\\
 \Eps: the neighbourhood distance \\
 \Min: the minimum number of points
 }
 \KwOut{\\Discovered outliers and clusters }
 \Var{\\
 \M, \N: row and column values of \D matrix, respectively\\
 \Dist: distance vector\\
 \Indices: indices that distance of points is lower than \Eps\\
 \Classn: indicates the clusters - default 1}
\BlankLine

\Alg{\\
    import the dataset into \D\\
    \For{$i \leftarrow 1$ \KwTo \M}{
        \Dist $\leftarrow \Distance(i, \D)$\\
        \Nei$\leftarrow$\Find(\Dist$\leq$\Eps)\\
        \Neic$\leftarrow$\Count(\Nei)\\
        \Core$\leftarrow$\Check(\Nei)\\
    
        \uIf{(\Neic$\geq$\Min)}{
            \Class($i$)$\leftarrow$\Classn\\
            \While{more points near $i$}{
                \Class(\Point)=\Classn
            }
            \Classn$\leftarrow$\Classn $+1$
        }
        \uElseIf{(\Neic$<$\Min$\&\&$\Core$==$true)}{
            \Class($i$)$\leftarrow 0$\tcc*[r]{border point}
        }
        \uElseIf{(\Neic$<$\Min)}{
            \Class($i$)$\leftarrow -1$\tcc*[r]{outlier point}
        }
    }
    \KwRet{\Class}
}
\BlankLine
\caption{DBSCAN \protect\cite{ccelik2011anomaly}}
\label{alg:db}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

Using a more complex prefix instead of the simple `@` will avoid such problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
That was quite helpful and fixed my problem.